# Horizontal Scroll in Listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am developing and android App, in which i need to show data as List view. In Each row there will be multiple record.

I just need to implement horizontal scroll on list view so that I can navigate it let right to see the content of listview.

I have tried [Android Horizontal ListView - Dev-Smart](http://www.dev-smart.com) . It show each record in single row. As i need to show each record in single row.

I need layout looks like below image.

[image: I need layout looks like attached image]

Please help.